# Beaglebone P8_3 to P8_10 doesn't toggle using Adafruit_BBIO

Tags: beagleboneblack

After installing the adafruit_bbio successfully on my beaglebone rev c 4gb ,with Ubuntu and simplecv ,written a python code which would toggle 16 LEDs starting from P8_3 to P8_18 the first 8 gpio pins doesn't toggle according to my code but the rest P8_11 to P8_18 toggles perfectly!!!Any help please?

Comment: Teo, It would probably help people to answer your question if you posted some of your python code. (in case there are any issues with how you're addressing those pins, or failing to set mode, etc)

Comment: I've found out searching more that only the pins that are pure GPIO works well!!all the other pins that involves mmc or spi or whatever else functionality they don't obey to that library!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the pin multiplexers configured to their GPIO modes. The pinmux is set through the AM335x's control module, which can only be configured from kernel space. If you're running the 3.8 kernel (`$ uname -r`) then the way to mux the pins is through the Device Tree. You need to either manually load your own overlays, or you could use the `universal-io` overlay and the `config-pin` command line utility.

You could also use the [PyBBIO](https://github.com/graycatlabs/PyBBIO) library, which includes Device Tree overlays for the GPIO pins and loads them automatically so you don't have to worry about writing your own.